# Generating link from Drop Down List and Cascade Drop Down List Values

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

What I need is for the Make_Name and Model_ID to go into a link after choosing them in the drop down and cascade drop down list and when you click the link, it will take you to a page where it displays all of those vehicles.

Tables Used:
Vehicle_Make has Make_ID and Make_Name and
Vehicle_Model has Model_ID and Model_Name

```
http://www.link.co.za/showroom/showroom.aspx?
s_MakeStr=BMW&s_RangeStr=&s_ModelStr=12&s_Province=0&s_MaxValue=0
```

So using the link above as an example, I'll need the "s_MakeStr" to come from the DropDown when I click the Make_Name, and then "s_ModelStr" which comes from the Vehicle_Model table (using Model_ID as PK) to come from the Cascade Drop Down when I click a Model_Name. "BMW" is the Make_Name and "12" is the Model_ID in the example link above.

Whenever I make a change in the two drop down lists, the link that's clickable should change to the new values.

Controller Code:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {    
        GoogleMapEntities GE = new GoogleMapEntities();
        List<Vehicle_Details> vehList = db.Vehicle_Details.ToList();

        GoogleMapViewModel GMviewmodel = new GoogleMapViewModel();
        List<GoogleMapViewModel> GMviewmodelList = new 
        List<GoogleMapViewModel>();


        //Populate the ViewModel
        MyPageViewModel vm = new Models.MyPageViewModel();
        vm.GoogleMapViewModelList = GMviewmodelList;
        vm.SelectedMake_Id = SelectedMake_Id;


        ViewBag.Vehicle_Make = new SelectList(db.GetVMSorted(), "Make_ID", 
        "Make_Name");

        return View(vm);               
        }

    public JsonResult GetModById(int MID)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        return Json(db.DropDL().Where(p => p.Make_ID == MID)
              .Select(p => new SelectListItem {Text = p.Model_Name + " " +  
    "- ("+p.Year + ")", Value = p.Model_ID.ToString()}).ToList(),
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Index.cshtml code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.SelectedMake_Id, ViewBag.Vehicle_Make as 
SelectList, "Select Vehicle Make", new { id = "ContID", @class = "form-
control", })

@Html.CascadingDropDownListFor(
expression: m => m.SelectedModelId,
triggeredByPropertyWithId: "ContID",  //Parent property that trigers 
dropdown data loading
url: Url.Action("GetModById", "Map"),  //Url of action that returns dropdown 
data
ajaxActionParamName: "MID", //Parameter name for the selected parent value 
that url action receives
optionLabel: "Please select a Model", // Option label
disabledWhenParentNotSelected: true, //If true, disables dropdown until 
parent dropdown is selected
htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "DDMDL" })
```

EDIT:

I have added a button code:

```
        var button = document.getElementById("btnSearch");

        button.onclick = function () {
        var text = document.getElementById("ContID").value;
        var text2 = document.getElementById("DDMDL").value;

        window.open("http://www.link.co.za/showroom/showroom.aspx?
        s_MakeStr=" + text + "&s_RangeStr=&s_ModelStr=" + text2 + 
        "&s_Province=0&s_MaxValue=0");
        }
```

And also the form code:

```
 <form>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="exampleInputEmail1">View Selected Model Range on Our 
 Site</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search">
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" 
 id="btnSearch">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

The link does work, but it's getting the ID values for text and text2. I need the strings, Make_Name and Model_Name, is it possible to do this without changing the code for the drop downs?

Please ignore the original question where I wanted the Model_ID to be searched for as well as I need the Model_Name instead of the ID.

Comment: You view does not contain a link. But why not just use a form with `FormMethod.Get`?

Comment: Sorry, this question was for how can I go about doing what I require, that is why I have posted all of the necessary code that I can hopefully get guidance on?

Comment: What have you tried? You need javascript to build a url based on the values of your form controls.

Comment: I have not tried anything as yet but I will try the FormMethod.Get just now. If I use this, then I do not have to make any changes to the controller ? I'll just have to work with the Index.cshtml right? As it will get values from the form. Just need to make sure because it should get me what I require.

Comment: Using a form with `FormMethod.Get` will post the values of all your controls withing the form to your method - it just needs parameters which match your `name` attributes (i.e. `SelectedMake_Id`, `SelectedModelId` etc)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, please read edit. It gets me the ID's but I realized that I need the Name's instead, how do I get those to go into the link instead of the ID's?

Comment: In jquery its `$('#ContID option:selected').text();`

Comment: Thanks it works! But I have another small issue. The model name in the cascade dd is "320i - (2011)" for example, I have it displaying the year as it makes it easier for a user to identify the vehicle. I want it to just take "320i" and search for that part only. Is there a way to edit the string in this piece of code " var text = $('#ContID option:selected').text();"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142162/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-captna).